What's inside APPDATA and will it be reinstalled if WSL Ubuntu files accidentally deleted?
I was installing WSL and got some problem with the environment variables after doing nano adding 'export $PATH' to the ~/.bashrc. The WSL no longer able to do 'ls' commands nor doing anything else. Feel stuck after countless reinstall through Microsoft Store, I look for the configuration files and finds out it was in %APPDATA folder. As soon as I see CanonicalUbuntu name in it, I immediately deletes it in expectation that windows store will reinstall it for me but it seems like it's not the case. I have look for solutions by learning what's inside %APPDATA and positive that reinstalling it should return it to what's it was before setting up but it no longer do what I expect it to do. Does anyone have similar experience and could tell me how to solve this problem? Of course I could dual-boot or install VM but I think (thought?) WSL is much easier and less hassle if this problem still could be solved somehow.
I tried looking for solution with similar problem in SuperUser but I don't think I need to hit the nuclear button yet am I?

Without knowing the contents of the folder I can't speak to how to generate the files again, however, files located in APPDATA are not critical the operation of Windows. So only WSL can create the file, and the WSL configuration file, isn't located in the directory you specified. Editing the Windows PATH variable wasn't the solution to bash issue.

@Ramhound What I was doing was editing the .bashrc. which were told as Linux configuration files where the PATH should be. Was I wrong already on that step? Then if it is true that WSL can create such files, why reinstalling it through store doesn't fix the problem? Did I miss something?

I will fall back to without you sharing the contents of the folder, I can’t reproduce the issue, as I don’t know what was contained in the folder.

@Ramhound Ah sorry, I cannot replicate it either since the folder is gone.. So the content maybe different between people? Where is the configuration file then? Maybe I can fix it there so the WSL finally reinstalls and remade the APPDATA files
